# Will plastic influence a magnetic field?

Tags: magnetics

First of all sorry for my English.
If, for example I will "create" magnet by passing current through a coil.
And than I will "wrap" this piece with plastic or some other material, will the "magnet power" (not really power..) And by "magnet lower" I mean the magnetic field will be influenced and will have "problem going throug" the plastic or other material piece?

Thanks!

Comment: I get an impression that you don't really know what an electromagnet is. Maybe you are describing an electrostaticly charged plate?

Comment: Hi Andy. Translating all the concepts from my language to English is pretty hard for me, so I might got it wrong writing one thing while meaning another thing. But I can assure you I know what an electromagnet is :).

Comment: You can't "make" metal into a magnet by charging it. You can make a magnet by passing current through a coil

Comment: That's exactly what I meant! :) I will edit my question

Comment: http://www.physlink.com/Education/AskExperts/ae512.cfm So the most likely effect will be nil.

Comment: No. All (except a few extremely rare) plastics have relative permeability almost equal to 1, which makes them 'transparent for magnetic field'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the exact type of plastic and the shape of the plastic sheath.

If the shape is the same the permittivity and permeability of the material can play some role on how the magnetic field shape, and if the material is conductive (there are conductive plastics) there is a whole another class of possibilities.

Comment: Yeah: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_magnet